# Padding between articles in css and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

As of right now my code is generating a random number of new articles in a div within my body. I am trying to make each article a tile of a different color which I am able to do. The issue I am having is the padding. I am new to web development and I am trying to make the vertical and horizontal spacing 15px. Here is what i have right now and it is not giving me the correct result

Also, I have used just "padding" and it was just going the border of all the articles rather than each individual one.

Comment: use css to style the elements... use class/element based rules instead of using jQuery to apply inline styling

Comment: And, in addition to that, if the space **between** elements should be 15px, use `margin`instead of `padding`. `padding` is **inside** elements, `margin` is **around**

Comment: Add the css style `article.box {}` and add your styles inside it

Comment: while the article.box make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8b4NL/)

By "article", do you mean a long text with lots of paragraphs/titles/subtitle?

JS

```
var randomcolor = ['#73EFF1','#D6C8F7','#F2C4DF', '#C4F2CD', '#F2EEC4', '#C4F2EF'];
$('div').each(function(){
    var random = Math.floor( Math.random() * ( (randomcolor.length - 0) + 1) ) + 0;
    var newcolor = randomcolor[random];
    $(this).css('background-color', newcolor);
  });
```